# Find external IP address of node js server in all scenarios

Tags: node.js, networking

I have build a node js code for an API server. Part of one feature is that when it starts, it should be able to know its own IP, despite the type of setup of the server where it is running.

The classic scenario is not that hard (I think). There are several options, like using the os module and find the ip or the external interface. I am sure there are other ways and some might be better, but this is the way I have been doing it so far. Feel free to add alternatives as informative as possible.

There is this case that I stumbled on. In one case, the web server was running on a google cloud instance. This instance has two IPs, one internal and one external. What I want is the external IP. However, when I use the method above, the actual external IP is not part of the object returned. The internal IP is declared as being considered as non-internal. Even when I run different commands from within the server command line, the only IP returned is the one that is actually internal and cannot be used to access the node server.

From what I understand, the instance itself is not aware of it's external IP. There might be a dns (I think) that redirects requests made to the external IP towards the correct instance.

While reading in the internet I read that problems getting the server's correct external IP might also rise when using load balancing or proxies.

The solution I thought about is to have the node js code make a request towards a service that I will build. This service will treat the node js servers as clients, and will return their external IPs. From experiments that I have done, the req object contains among others the information of the client's IP. So I should check first **req.connection.remoteAddress** and then the first element of **req.headers['x-forwarded-for']**. Ideally the server would make a request towards itself, but

I know there are external API like https://api.ipify.org?format=json that do just that - return the actual IP. But I would very much like to have the node js servers independent of services I cannot control.

However, I really am hoping that there are better solutions out there than making a request from the server which returns the server IP.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way for the server to know its public IP in all configurations without asking an external observer (like the service you cite).

Comment: What solution did you come up with at the end?

Comment: @EMX : I ended up building my own service, which so far has proved to work for the scenarios we have tested.

Comment: Nice, good to know your question got solved. If my answer has been of any help, please remember to vote/mark. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I really am hoping that there are better solutions out there
>   than making a request from the server which returns the server IP.

It is not really possible, you always rely on some kind of external observer / external request.

> While reading in the internet I read that problems getting the
>   server's correct external IP might also rise when using load balancing
>   or proxies.

This is because **not in all scenarios** your own device is able to be self-aware of its external ip. There might be sitting behind some network, that means external address assigned to devices that forwards the WAN to it. (example : router) so when you try to obtain external ip from the devices interface itself, you end up obtaining an ip but inside the scope of the routers LAN and not the one used for external requests .

So if you really want to

1. Have a method to use **in all scenarios**
2. Not rely on 3rd party services

**Only Solution :**
Build your own ip echo service (you maintain and can use for future projects).